# I cannot access my Magento website and even the admin section

Tags: magento-1.7, error

I was trying to install, in Magento connect, a extension called Multisite Integration for WordPress from FISHPIG.

Then I click refresh. Then it send me this message: Module "Fishpig_Wordpress_Multisite" requires module "Fishpig_Wordpress"...

So I try to go back with the back button on the browser but the only thing I could see was the same message. So then I tried to access the admin section of my Magento. Then I got this error message: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

The server temp. unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

My question is: how can I get out of this?

I tried this in my MySQL: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; but with no luck.

**UPDATE**

I was able to access my admin panel by removing: maintenance file.

But when I access the Magento connect I just get this message:  Module "Fishpig_Wordpress_Multisite" requires module "Fishpig_Wordpress"

With no options. What do I do to get out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Magento Connect installs an extension, it puts Magento in "maintenance" mode (unless you've unchecked this option).

It sounds like your extension installation bailed in the middle, and for some reason (either a bug or poor design), Magento failed to flip the system out of maintenance mode.

You'll need to put Magento back into it's normal mode.  To do this, simply remove the

```
maintenance.flag
```

from the top level Magento folder.

Comment: Thanks. But now it's my Magento connect that is locking me out. With just one message.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your updated question:

If your website still shows Module "Fishpig_Wordpress_Multisite" requires module "Fishpig_Wordpress":

1. Go to app/etc/modules/Fishpig_Wordpress_Multisite.xml and set  to false so that you deactivate this module and the error disappears
2. Log into your Backend and Magento connect
3. Install Fishpig_Wordpress
4. Activate Fishpig_Wordpress_Multisite again